# Checkbox reveal which items are selected on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

on my page a user can select multiple items.
I use a checkbox and iterate over all the items of a user.
Now I want to show the user the total price of all the items he selected on that page.
So to say the total price of the shopping cart.

How can I access the ids of my items on the same page that the user clicks on them? I know that in the controller I can access them by

```
Item.find(params[:items])
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this via Javascript.

One way is to store the id in the [`data`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_data.asp) tags of your html element (`checkbox` in this case)

Then you can get this value in your Javascript callback as

```
element.getAttribute('data-type');
```

or if you are using jQuery

```
$(this).data("id")
```

Now you will need to access the value of the item (individual price for the item with the selected id) as well in Javascript. You can do this by either storing the mapping of id to price in a js variable

```
let prices = <%= @items.select(:id, :price).to_json %>;
```

or alternatively, you can just store the price in a data-attribute of each checkbox, and use this value to update the total selected price.